# How to prove that one can pull an existential quantification out of a universal quantification using a cartesian product of the quantified elements?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, set-theory

Assume that $A$ is an index set and $\{ B_a \}_{a \in A}$ is a family of sets indexed by the elements of $A$. Then, I would like to prove the following identity:

$$
\forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b)))
\Longleftrightarrow
\exists c \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a (\forall a \in A (P(a, c_a)))
$$

Going from left to right, the idea is that for all $a \in A$ there is a $b \in B_a$ satisfying $P(a, b)$. Let's call that one $b_a$. Then $c = (b_a | a \in A)$ (the ordered tuple consisting of each $b_a$) will be an element of $\prod_{a \in A} B_a$ such that for all $a \in A$, $c_a$ will simply be $b_a$ and so by construction of $b_a$, $P(a, c_a)$ will hold.

Going from right to left, if we assume that there exists such a $c \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a$, we can, for all $a \in A$, easily construct a $b \in B_a$ that satisfies $P(a, b)$ by simply choosing $b = c_a$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to formalize this proof as it feels very "intuitive" to me. Furthermore, it "feels" like this statement should have a simple proof that goes in both directions, but I can't seem to unify the two directions of the proof into one proof.

How do I formally write down the proof of this statement? Is there an elegant proof of this statement which works in both directions?

Comment: What you are attempting to prove is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: How so? There is clearly some choice function that allows me to choose each element of the tuple such that it fulfills the $P$, so I don't think I need to invoke the axiom of choice.

Comment: One statement of the axiom of choice states that for all indexed families of sets $\{B_a\}_{a \in A}$, if every $B_a$ has an element, then $\prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$ has an element. Clearly, this follows from your formulation. Therefore, your formulation cannot be proved without the axiom of choice (unless set theory itself is inconsistent). As for asserting there is "clearly" some choice function, it sounds like you have a philosophical conviction in the axiom of choice. But there are good reasons not to, especially if you are a constructivist.

Comment: I don't think that the axiom of choice follows from my statement. My statement only implies that the cartesian product has a certain element if $\{ B_a \}_{a \in A}$ follows a certain property which endows it with a choice function. That choice function being the one that selects from each $B_a$ that $b$ such that $P(a, b)$ holds. So if we require a property that implies the existence of this choice function, we won't imply the axiom of choice.

Comment: The predicate is $P(a, b) = \top$. Stating that $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))$ is exactly the statement that every $B_a$ has an element. Your formulation then requires the existence of some $c \in \prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$; we have thus proved the axiom of choice. Conversely, assume the axiom of choice. We can define $D_a = \{b \in B_a \mid P(a, b)\}$. Every $D_a$ has an element, so $\prod\limits_{a \in A} D_a \subseteq \prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$ also has an element $c$; clearly, for all $a$, we must have $P(a, c_a)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since my comments have multiplied, I’ll go ahead and answer the question.

The right-to-left implication is indeed, as OP shows, quite trivial to prove. The left-to-right implication, on the other hand, is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

The statement of the axiom of choice I will use is:

> Suppose we have a set $A$ and an indexed family $\{B_a\}_{a \in A}$. Suppose for all $a \in A$, there is some element of $B_a$. Then there is some element of $\prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$.

For suppose the left-to-right implication always holds. Then consider some indexed family $\{B_a\}_{a \in A}$ of sets, where for all $a \in A$, there is some $b \in B_a$. Let $P(a, b) :\equiv \top$; then we have $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))$. Then there is some $c \in \prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$. We have proved choice.

Conversely, assume the axiom of choice, and consider some indexed family $\{B_a\}_{a \in A}$ such that $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))$. Then define $D_a = \{b \in B_a \mid P(a, b)\}$ using the axiom scheme of separation (the weaker axiom of $\Delta_0$-separation suffices when $P(a, b)$ is $\Delta_0$). Then each $D_a$ has an element, so by the axiom of choice, there is some $c \in \prod\limits_{a \in A} D_a \subseteq \prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$. We see immediately that for all $a \in A$, we must have $P(a, c_a)$ since $c_a \in D_a$. $\square$

We know that the axiom of choice does not follow from the other axioms of set theory (unless these other axioms of set theory are themselves inconsistent - let’s hope that’s not true, since it would be a major crisis for mathematics). So we cannot prove the left-to-right implication without using the axiom of choice, since this would let us prove the axiom of choice itself from set theory’s other axioms, which cannot be done.

With some usual axioms, we can strengthen our result even further. Recall the axiom scheme of strong collection, which states:

> Suppose that for all $a \in A$, there is some $b$ such that $P(a, b)$. Then there exists some set $B$, which satisfies the following two properties: (1) for all $a \in A$, there is some $b \in B$ such that $P(a, b)$, and (2) for all $b \in B$, there is some $a \in A$ such that $P(a, b)$.

We assume the axiom scheme of strong collection (which I just call “collection”), together with the axiom of choice. Then we have the following:

> Suppose that for all $a \in A$, there exists some $b$ such that $P(a, b)$. Then there is some function $f$ with domain $A$ such that for all $a \in A$, we have $P(a, f(a))$.

Proof: define $Q(a, b) :\equiv \exists c (b = (a, c) \land P(a, c))$. Clearly, $\forall a \in A \exists b (Q(a, b))$. By the axiom scheme of collection, we can find some set $B$ such that $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B (Q(a, b))$ and such that $\forall b \in B \exists a \in A (Q(a, b))$.

Now define $B_a = \{c \mid \exists a \in A ((a, c) \in B)\}$ - this definition works using replacement, which follows from collection. Then $\forall a \in A \exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))$. In particular, every $B_a$ has an element. So there is some $f \in \prod\limits_{a \in A} B_a$. Furthermore, we see that $\forall a \in A \forall b \in B_a (P(a, b))$. So we have found the $f$ we are looking for. $\square$

The axiom scheme of strong collection follows from the combination of replacement, the full law of excluded middle, and foundation. The fact that foundation is apparently necessary is quite curious and intriguing.

Technical note for people who love logic: When one is dealing with intuitionist set theories (where the full law of excluded middle does not hold) and not assuming the full strength of the axiom scheme of separation, one can typically add the scheme of full collection “for free” - there is a broad class $C$ of mathematical statements where you can algorithmically transform a proof of some statement in $C$ which uses strong collection into a proof of the same statement which doesn’t use it. Adding the axiom of choice then gives you a rather unusual situation - you can prove a weak version of the law of excluded middle, that any set either has an element or is empty, but you cannot prove all instances of excluded middle.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. As far as I understand now, the problem with my statement of "Why isn't it possible to let $c$ be a tuple that holds exactly the $b$s whose existence we just asserted?" is that we don't have a choice function to pick which of the $b$s that fulfill the property we want. So there might be multiple $b$s per $a$ that fulfill the property, so we need the axiom of choice in order to pick one for each $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have discovered a proof.
Assume that $A$ is an index set and $\{ B_a \}_{a \in A}$ is a family of sets indexed by the elements of $A$.
The cartesian product in this case will be:
$$ \prod_{a \in A} B_a = \{ c \mid \forall a \in A (c_a \in B_a) \} $$
Then:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}c}}
                    & \forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \forall a \in A (\exists b (b \in B_a \land P(a, b))) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \exists c (\forall a \in A (c_a \in B_a \land P(a, c_a))) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \exists c (\forall a \in A (c_a \in B_a) \land \forall a \in A (P(a, c_a))) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \exists c \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a (\forall a \in A (P(a, c_a))) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Comment: And what justifies your second equivalence? Isn't this exactly the step you're asking about in the original question?

Comment: (The answer is: it is justified by the axiom of choice.)

Comment: "And what justifies your second equivalence? Isn't this exactly the step you're asking about in the original question?" You're correct.

Comment: "The answer is: it is justified by the axiom of choice." But the axiom of choice only asserts the existence of some element of the cartesian product, not the existence of the element I need (the one that fulfills the given property). Again, I don't see why I can't just construct that element. The second line states the existence of an appropriate $b$ for each $a$, so why isn't it possible to let $c$ be a tuple that holds exactly the $b$s whose existence is asserted by the second line?