# Is this proof that one can pull an existential quantification out of a universal quantification using a cartesian product of the power set correct?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, set-theory

This is a follow-up to my previous question ([How to prove that one can pull an existential quantification out of a universal quantification using a cartesian product of the quantified elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467123/how-to-prove-that-one-can-pull-an-existential-quantification-out-of-a-universal)).

In that previous question, I asked about a proof for the following statement:
$$
\forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b)))
\Longleftrightarrow
\exists c \in \prod_{a \in A} B_a (\forall a \in A (P(a, c_a)))
$$
The idea there was that if for any $a$, there exists an appropriate $b$, we can simply store all the $b$'s in a tuple indexed by the $a$'s. However, as was pointed out, the problem with this was that for some $a$, there may exist multiple appropriate $b$'s, so we need the Axiom of Choice in order to choose some $b$ to store in the tuple.

So, my idea is now that instead of trying to make a choice by storing one $b$ per $a$ in the tuple, we can simply store a tuple of sets that contains the set of all appropriate $b$'s for a certain $a$. Then we won't need to make a choice and don't need to invoke the Axiom of Choice.

Let $A$ be an index set and $\{ B_a \}_{a \in A}$ is a family of sets indexed by the elements of $A$. I claim the following statement:

$$
\forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b)))
\Longleftrightarrow
\exists C \in \prod_{a \in A} (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}) (\forall a \in A (\forall c \in C_a (P(a, c))))
$$

Where the cartesian product is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*3c}
\prod_{a \in A} (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \})
& = & \{ C \mid \forall a \in A (C_a \in (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \})) \} \\
& = & \{ C \mid \forall a \in A (C_a \not = \emptyset \land C_a \subseteq B_a) \} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

From right to left:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*2c}
                & \exists C \in \prod_{a \in A} (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}) (\forall a \in A (\forall c \in C_a (P(a, c)))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \exists C (\forall a \in A (C_a \not = \emptyset \land C_a \subseteq B_a \land \forall c \in C_a (P(a, c)))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \exists C (\forall a \in A (C_a \subseteq B_a \land \exists c \in C_a (P(a, c)))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \exists C (\forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b)))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

From left to right:

$$ \forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b))) $$

Let $\displaystyle (C_a)_{a \in A}$ (a tuple of sets indexed by the elements of $A$) such that $\displaystyle \forall a \in A (C_a = \{ b \in B_a \mid P(a, b) \})$. Therefore $\forall a \in A(C_a \subseteq B_a \land \forall c \in C_a (P(a, c)))$.

We've assumed $\displaystyle \forall a \in A (\exists b \in B_a (P(a, b)))$, therefore $\displaystyle \forall a \in A (\exists c \in C_a)$ and therefore $\displaystyle \forall a \in A (C_a \not = \emptyset)$.

Therefore:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{*2c}
                & \forall a \in A (C_a \not = \emptyset \land C_a \subseteq B_a \land \forall c \in C_a (P(a, c))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \exists C (\forall a \in A (C_a \not = \emptyset \land C_a \subseteq B_a \land \forall c \in C_a (P(a, c)))) \\
\Longrightarrow & \exists C \in \prod_{a \in A} (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}) (\forall a \in A (\forall c \in C_a (P(a, c)))) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Since the expression on the left side follows from the one on the right side and vice versa, they're equivalent.

I realize that in my construction, I am still claiming the existence of a certain cartesian product. However, I don't think that I need to invoke the Axiom of Choice here. This is because I am explicitly constructing the subset that I want to choose: The one whose elements all fulfill the property. Since this exactly defines the subset, I don't think that I need to make an arbitrary choice.

Am I correct that the proof of this statement (unlike the proof of the statement I claimed previously) does not require the Axiom of Choice, and is my proof correct?

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer that the proof doesn't contain mistakes, but does it work choicelessly? You're assuming existence of a Cartesian product, each of whose arguments is constructed explicitly (I think this is OK). But the ordering of the $a\in A$ used to define sequences $C$ is not explicit (I'm not sure if this is OK?) For example, what is the underlying ordering of one of the sequences $C\in\prod_{a\in\mathbb R}(P(B_a)\setminus\{\varnothing\})$?

Comment: @C7X I don't think I need the index set to have any underlying ordering. As far as I understand, as long as I explicitely give the choice function that chooses the $C_a \in (\mathcal{P}(B_a) \setminus \{ \emptyset \})$ for all $a$, I don't need to invoke the Axiom of Choice in order to construct the cartesian product.

Comment: My concern was that $\Pi_{a\in\mathbb R}(P(B_a)\setminus\{\varnothing\})$ being a sequence would mean there has to be an underlying ordering on it, e.g. it would make sense to talk about $B_x$ coming before $B_y$ in the sequence. But if it's more like a map whose outputs aren't inherently ordered, you're right.

Comment: @C7X Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof does look correct. And it doesn't require the Axiom of Choice. In fact, it constructs exactly the sort of set one might then apply the Axiom of Choice on as a next step.